# Transform java code into one regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I need help transforming the **equals** code into **matches(regex)**. Thanks a lot.

```
    //string composed of prefix and suffix - Can be spaced
    //PREFIX - alfa-numeric, variable length, upper/lower case
    //SUFFIX - numeric, variable length, can be spaced
    String str="xpto 123 456 789";

    String prefix_to_search="XPTO";
    String digits_to_search="123456789";

    //remove prefix (case insensitive)
    str.substring(str.toUpperCase().startsWith(prefix_to_search) ? prefix_to_search.length() : 0).
    //remove spaces
    replace(" ","").
    equals(digits_to_search));
```

Given a string "xpto 123 456 789"

**MATCH**
"123456789"
"123 456 789"
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
"XPTO 123 456 789"
"XPTO 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

**NOT MATCH**
"12345678"
"1234567890"
"XPTO 12345678"
"XPTO 1234567890"
"XP 123 456 789"
"123 456 789 XPTO"

In other words:
- prefix must be IGNORED (case INSENSITVE!)
- Numbers must MATCH (spaces must be IGNORED!)

Comment: Remember, you can also try it in www.regexr.com

Comment: Why?  If you have code that works, do you really need to change it?

Comment: It's to be applied on a QUERY! I don't have all the String functions available, but i can use "matches"!

Comment: Is the order of the digits important?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output because it's easier for the users here to come up with a solution.

Comment: Expected output provided!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?i)(?:xpto)?\\s*1\\s*2\\s*3\\s*4\\s*5\\s*6\\s*7\\s*8\\s*9
```

If you want to have always a match with the prefix too, remove the `?` after the prefix group (from your update it seemed to me the prefix is not mandatory)

Answer (score -1):

This should do it (assuming that it is specific to this question)

```
(?i)\bxpto[0-9\W]+
```

You can go and check it on www.regexplanet.com

Comment: @marcolopes       instead of saying "It doesn't work" please post your expected output so that we can understand what exactly you are expecting. You have been asked to do this by other users to do this and all you are saying "It doesn't work"....